# how to return keyboard focus to screen in safari after exiting fullscreen

Tags: javascript, safari

In safari and vivaldi keyboard control doesn't work after returning from full screen.
A mouse click in the screen will make it work again, but window.focus() will not.

I found a kind-of-solution:

```
function regainFocusOnExitFullScreen(){
     document.querySelector('.my-button').focus();
     document.querySelector('.my-button').blur();
}
```

The querySelector('.my-button') is not guaranteed to work if the user doesn't have buttons. I'm not sure what to use as a general case.

Comment: You could use a list of all focusable elements then just focus on the first, e.g. `var el = document.querySelectorAll('input, button, select'); if (el) {el = el[0].focus(); el[0].blur()}` or similar (I've not listed all focusable elements).

Comment: what about if there weren't focusable elements?  I'm using reveal.js, and I could make it work when there were buttons, but you can turn off the navigation buttons, so then there is only sections.

Comment: Maybe try putting a button in the DOM, do focus/blur, remove the button.